# Anything above Minecraft 1.8 Crashes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

And it says this in the log.

```
2017-08-19 10:00:28,533 main ERROR Unable to move file C:\Users\Uncetic\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs\latest.log to C:\Users\Uncetic\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs\2017-08-19-2.log: java.nio.file.FileSystemException C:\Users\Uncetic\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs\latest.log -> C:\Users\Uncetic\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs\2017-08-19-2.log: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

2017-08-19 10:00:28,570 main ERROR Unable to delete file C:\Users\Uncetic\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs\latest.log: java.nio.file.FileSystemException C:\Users\Uncetic\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs\latest.log: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

  <log4j:Event logger="bhz" timestamp="1503154829118" level="INFO" thread="Client thread">
    <log4j:Message><![CDATA[Setting user: Uncetic]]></log4j:Message>
  </log4j:Event>
```

Can someone please explain a fix to this problem?

Comment: You're probably going to get a better response if you explain your problem a little more.  Just showing us your error log usually isn't enough to get a good answer.  What else were you doing at the time?  Were you running any other applications that might access the Minecraft folder?  You don't have to give every last detail, but you should be verbose in your problem description.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a program has one of your log files open.  This may be from a running program, like Minecraft itself, or a text editor, like Note Pad.  Make sure any programs like that are closed and try again.  If that doesn't work try deleting your log files.  They're located in `.minecraft\logs`.  If that still doesn't help restart your computer.